# Android Chronometer countdown completion

Tags: java, android, xml, timer, countdowntimer

I am trying to implement timer into my white noise app.

App has 4 buttons to set different tunes, and 4 function buttons: play/pause, stop, one_hour and three_hours. These last two are running in countdown mode.

```
private Chronometer chronometer;
private boolean running;
private long pauseOffset;

switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.play_button:
            if (choosenAudio.isPlaying()) {
                //logic here
                pauseChronometer();
                break;
            }
            else {
                //logic here
                startChronometer();
                break;
            }

        case R.id.stop_button:
            //logic here
            resetChronometer();
            chronometer.setCountDown(false);
            chronometer.stop();
            break;

        case R.id.one_hour:
            //logic here
            chronometer.setCountDown(true);
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 3600000);
            pauseOffset = 0;
            chronometer.start();
            break;

        case R.id.three_hours:
            //logic here
            chronometer.setCountDown(true);
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10800000);
            pauseOffset = 0;
            chronometer.start();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

My methods:

```
public void startChronometer() {
    if (!running) {chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
        chronometer.start();
        running = true;
    }

}

public void pauseChronometer() {
    if (running) {
        chronometer.stop();
        pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
        running = false;
    }

}

public void resetChronometer() {
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    pauseOffset = 0;

}
```

My question:

How can I detect and make something (i.e. stop music) when countdown time reaches 00:00?

Thank you all!

Comment: any update on this? have u find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

use must use `setOnChronometerTickListener` listener like this

```
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
              long time = chronometer.getBase();
              //Use this time for finding minute and seconds
           }
     });
```

Comment: how is this helping?